# Drupal Adding Font Style to Date Fields

Tags: theming

Sorry i thought i should ask this here as apposed to your CSS site as ive a feeling its something that Drupal is doing and not just a general css question.

When viewing the last comment time on the right of the main table of this page (and taxonony table pages) you will see that something is adding an  tag to my date field.
[My site with the em added](http://onlinebanter.com/latest)

The norm12 span class is what i have added and you can see that even making the font-style: normal with important added its still showing it with  tags and style about it.

Its only a minor problem but its driving me mad.

Can anyone see where the problem may lie?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reg your trying override this on the span but the em tag has the style defined on it.

Should be...

```
.norm12 em {
//...
}
```

Comment: ah brilliant thanks Alex. thats the one. Afer about 6 years of trying i am getting a hang of this css business. (believe it or not) There seems to be so many ways to select a thing and that confuses me. What you just posted though makes perfect sense to me now. durrr

Comment: No worries, depending what browser you use you should have some dev tools built in that makes it quicker/easier to determine whats going on.

Comment: I find Firefox + Firebug extremely useful while dealing with CSS: right click on the element and choose "Inspect Element with Firebug". Give it a go, you won't regret it.